# Get path to current executing unit test in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can you get a `File` or `Uri` representing the path to the currently executing unit test in Flutter? More specifically, just the folder of the running test.

The path may not necessary be the location of the currently executing *code*, such as in the case the code is running in a file other than the currently executing test.

Neither `Platform.script` nor `Directory.current` work within unit tests.

For example, you might want to create your own implementation of a golden test (such as storing and comparing to a text file instead of an image) and need to create a file in the current test's directory.

I already know an answer to this question, which I've posted below, but it seems very "unofficial". The purpose of this post is 1) see if anyone has a better answer and 2) help others by documenting my solution.

Comment: I wish there would be an answer which could be used for dart cli apps, without any flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the `basedir` from the LocalFileComparator.**

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

final Uri basedir = (goldenFileComparator as LocalFileComparator).basedir;
```

Output:
`file:///path/to/project/your_project/test/path/to/test/`

---

The [`goldenFileComparator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/goldenFileComparator.html) is a global variable which represents the current method of comparing [golden tests](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/matchesGoldenFile.html). By default while executing tests, the Flutter test framework sets it to a `LocalFileComparator`, which is provided the base test directory upon creation. See [the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/goldenFileComparator.html) for more details on the implementation.

The assignment of this comparator is done deep within the testing framework, meaning it is impossible to retrieve the basedir in the same way that the framework does to create the LocalFileComparator. Borrowing the value from the LocalFileComparator seems to be the only way.

It is possible for a developer to change the goldenFileComparator to their own implementation, causing the cast to fail. This scenario should be taken into consideration.

Comment: It throws 'TrivialComparator' is not a subtype of type 'LocalFileComparator

Comment: @L3odr0id See the documentation of [TrivialComparator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/TrivialComparator-class.html).

"Placeholder comparator that is set as the value of goldenFileComparator when the initialization that happens in the test bootstrap either has not yet happened or has been bypassed. The only case where we expect it to remain uninitialized is when the user runs a test via flutter run".

How are you running the test?

Comment: I tried to take a look at how Flutter initializes `LocalFileComparator` https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/36f97fc0e02c34e2769b819d69399dd23f0c38ca/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/test/flutter_platform.dart#L129 From what I understood they are launching test process themselves and they get to pick the path to the test. This doesn't work for me as I want to find something similar for dart-only tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `StackTrace.current` to get a path to the current test or any piece of code.

```
    final line = StackTrace.current.toString().split("\n").firstOrNull;
    print(line);
    if (line == null) return;
    final left = line.indexOf("(") + 1;
    final right = line.indexOf(":", left + 5);
    final fileName = line.substring(left, right);
    print(fileName);
```

This code requires some cleaning up and improvement. Here are my results:

```
#0      main.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/tm/stax/cli/test/cli/log/single_commit.dart:17:29)
file:///Users/tm/stax/cli/test/cli/log/single_commit.dart
```

You can clearly see that stack trace gives us a line that contains a file name, and that file name was successfully extracted in this case.

Note this method works both in flutter and dart tests, while `goldenFileComparator as LocalFileComparator` works only for flutter tests.